# compiler "error: passing ‘const something’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers"

Tags: c++

I am making a custom list using templates in C++ and get some compilation error.
The code is very large in length , so here is a small snippet of the code from where the error is coming. Compilation error is given below. You can compile it your own system to see the same error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class sortedList
{
    int m_count;
    public:
    sortedList(){m_count = 0;}
    int length(){ return m_count; }

};


    void output(const sortedList<int>& list)
    {
        cout << "length" << list.length() << endl;
        return;
    }

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    sortedList <int> list1;
    output(list1);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting compilation error :

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void output(const sortedList<int>&)’:
prog.cpp:17:35: error: passing ‘const sortedList<int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   cout << "length" << list.length() << endl;
                                   ^
prog.cpp:10:6: note:   in call to ‘int sortedList<T>::length() [with T = int]’
  int length(){ return m_count; }
```

Comment: You are calling non-const-qualified method `length` on const-qualified object `list`. Make `length()` const-qualified.

Comment: `int length(){ return m_count; }`-> `int length() const { return m_count; }`

Comment: Did you read the error? Do you understand what it's saying?

Comment: You should learn what const means in C++ and how to ensure const correctness. This is covered in introductory C++ textbooks.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to make `length` to be const-qualified:

```
int length(){ return m_count; }
```

→

```
int length() const { return m_count; }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. As already mentioned, one option is to make `length` const-qualified.
2. Another option is to use const_cast within the `output` function.

> ```
> sortedList<int>& ref = const_cast <sortedList<int>&>(list);
> cout << "length" << ref.length() << endl;
> ```

(2) is especially useful when we don't have the luxury to update the class method mentioned in (1).